# uninitialized error in foreach loop

Tags: perl

Trying to use https://grepular.com/projects/IMAPExpire

```
$ ./imapexpire.pl --test --user user --passfile ~/imapexpire.pass --folders exceptions --age 100 --host myserver
TEST  : You're running in test mode, so the deletions wont actually take place
ACTION: Delete mail which arrived before 27-Jan-2015 from: exceptions
Use of uninitialized value $line in substitution (s///) at /usr/local/share/perl5/IMAP/Client.pm line 560, <GEN0> line 14.
```

Client.pm:555:

```
sub parse_search (@) {
    my (@resp) = @_;
    my @results = ();
    # find SEARCH line and process results
    foreach my $line (@resp) {
        next unless ($line =~ s/^\*\s+SEARCH\s+([\d+\s]+)\s*\r\n$/$1/);
                @results = split(/ /,$line);
                last; # theres only 1 line
    }
    return(wantarray ? @results : @results ? sequencify(@results) : undef );
}
```

If `$line` is uninitialized, why did `foreach` iterate?

I'm on RHEL 6.5 . Ran `yum install perl-IO-Socket-SSL` and `cpan IMAP::Client`.

Comment: You have certainly an undefined values in `@resp`. What is the result of `Dumper\@resp;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an array can contain an `undef`.

```
my @list_of_things = ( "fish", undef, "carrot" ); 

foreach my $line ( @list_of_things ) { 
   print $line;
}
```

You are presumably having an `undef` injected via `@resp` but without seeing what's going in there I can't tell whence it comes.

A workaround might be:

```
next unless defined $line;
```